# my multiple versions of jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I would like to use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page.
I wrote below but two scripts doesn't work.
Could you teach me what is worong my code pleaes?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jpostal-1006.appspot.com/jquery.jpostal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
var $330 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Here is my whole JS part

https://jsfiddle.net/blueink/8m7oLzsf/1/

one is postal code script which uses jquery-2.1.0.min.js and jpostal.js
second script is livesearch which uses 3.3.0.

Comment: So why are you loading 2 versions in the first place? Most likely both of those plugins would  work using a common version

Comment: Your noconflict need to be before your first jquery otherwise your second will override the first and then be set to no conflict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: Yes it is possible see answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you need to call `$.noConflict()` on the first instance of jQuery before you add the second. Therefore if you want to keep `$` as a reference to 2.1.0, add that second.

Also note that your reference to `jquery.jpostal.js`, which relies on jQuery, needs to be placed after both of these references.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var $330 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jpostal-1006.appspot.com/jquery.jpostal.js"></script>

<!-- Just for demonstration purposes -->
<script>
  console.log($.fn.jquery)
  console.log($330.fn.jquery);
</script>
```

With all of that said, requiring multiple versions of jQuery in one site is far from ideal, and *will* become a maintenance problem in the future. Your time would be well spent addressing the issues you have upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Dear @Rory McCrossan Thank you so much! I appreciate! that was perfect answer and explain. THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem, glad to help